# How to deploy the kafka connect in a distributed mode?

Tags: distributed, apache-kafka-connect

I am working on building the Kafka-connect application using JDBC sink connector in kubernetes. I tried the Standalone mode and it is working. I would like to move to the distributed mode.
I can successfully build up two pods (kafka connector) by running yaml file below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: vtq
  name: kafka-sink-postgres-dis
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-sink-postgres-dis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka-sink-postgres-dis
        image: ***
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

bin/connect-distributed.sh config/worker.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=***:9092
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

rest.port=8083
rest.host.name=127.0.0.1


key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://schema-registry:8081


# Prevent the connector from pulling all historical messages
auto.offset.reset=latest

# options below may be required for distributed mode

# unique name for the cluster, used in forming the Connect cluster group. Note that this must not conflict with consumer group IDs
group.id=connect-postgres-sink-dis

# Topic to use for storing offsets. This topic should have many partitions and be replicated.
offset.storage.topic=postgres-connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=3

# Topic to use for storing connector and task configurations; note that this should be a single partition, highly replicated topic.
# You MUST manually create the topic to ensure single partition for the config topic as auto created topics may have multiple partitions.

config.storage.topic=postgres-connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=3

# Topic to use for storing statuses. This topic can have multiple partitions and should be replicated.
status.storage.topic=postgres-connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=3
```

And created one sink connector inside of each pod with task.max=1 and the two connectors listened to the same topic. It turned out to be that they just duplicated.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name": "postgres_sink_dis", "config": {"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector", "tasks.max":"1", "connection.url":"***","topics":"***"}}' http://127.0.0.1:8083/connectors
```

But I am quite confusing by the concepts of kafka connect cluster, the workers, the connectors, the tasks. I read from 
https://github.com/enfuse/kafka-connect-demo/blob/master/docs/install-connector.md. 
They Set up port-forwarding to the rest port before configuring the connector. I tried with that and after deploying the service and creating the connector, there is no return for curl -s 172.0.0.1:8083/connectors.

Can anyone give me a short description what should I do next and any relevant information would be very helpful. Thanks!

**UPDATES:**
Finally, I figured out the issue and solved the problem. 
1. Deploy two pods/workers separately with the same group.id and different rest.port (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html).
2. Inside the pod, create a connector with tasks.

Answer (score 1):

For example you have a connector cluster of two workers/two pods. You can create connectors ( sink or source ) with several tasks in the cluster and these tasks will be distributed in the two workers.

Comment: @ Dipperman I deployed my pods in two nodes by setting replicas as 2. And created one sink connector inside of each pod with task.max=1 and the two connectors listened to the same topic. It turned out to be that they just duplicated. They are send the same message to my postgres. The work is not really distributed. One thing to point out, my topic setting is by default, only having one partition. Would that be a problem? Or something wrong with my config?

Comment: you have to configure the same group.id in each pod. Distributed workers that are configured with matching group.id values automatically discover each other and form a cluster.

Comment: What you should have is a deployment with replica 2. If you make two nodes with replica two, in same form you are creating two differents clusters each one with two workers. That's why you have duplicate messages in the postgres. Your pods/workers should have rest.advertised.host.name differents between them.

Comment: If it is not a production enviorenment: 1.-Stop the connectors, 2.-Delete the topics config.storage.topic, offset.storage.topic, status.storage.topic, 3.-recreate the topics 4.-Create a deployment with replica two each worker with different rest.advertised.host.name and each worker with same group.id 5.-Check if everithing is ok 5.- You will have one cluster with two workers, one sink connector and just one task in any of the workers.

Comment: Thanks! At step 4, I don't know how to have different properties by using replica 2. Instead, I create two pods separately with identical group.id but different rest.advertised.host.name. Problems occurs when I try to create a connector inside the pod with command "curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{...}' http://localhost:8083/connectors", error message "{"error_code":500,"message":"Invalid URI host: null (authority: sink_conn_w2:8083)"}". sink_conn_w2:8083 is the leaderURL of the pod and sink_conn_w2 is the rest.advertised.host.name in the first pod.

Comment: try this: curl localhost:8083/connectors/

Comment: Finally I figured out by using different rest.port in the configuration. I have updated my findings above. Thank for your help.